# PHP- Check if any $_GET variable exists in URL

Tags: php

I can use this to find out if a specific `$_GET` variable is set:

```
if (isset($_GET['this'])) {
```

However, I am trying to check if ANY `$_GET` variables exist. So, I do:

```
if (isset($_GET)) {

  return true;

} else {

  return false;

}
```

I have also used:

```
if (is_array($_GET))
```

The problem is, no matter what even with no `$_GET` variables in the URL, it always returns `TRUE`.

What is the proper way of checking if ANY `$_GET` variables exist without having to specify which one specifically?

Comment: `if(!empty($_GET())`

Comment: there's also `if(count($_GET)>0){ ...`